# Get the Date type in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using date picker "hijri date picker" ,I want to know how I can get if the date selected is hijri or Gregorian?

That's my code:

```
$("#txtDateOfBirthApplicant").hijriDatePicker({
    locale: 'en-us',
    hijriText: "Hijri Calendar",
    gregorianText: "Gregorian Calendar",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similiar:

```
const datepickerSettings =
{
  locale: 'en-us',
  hijri: false, // false => gregorian, true => hijri
  hijriText: "Hijri Calendar",
  gregorianText: "Gregorian Calendar",
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txtDateOfBirthApplicant').hijriDatePicker(datepickerSettings);
   let dateType = datepickerSettings.hijri ? 'hijri' : 'gregorian';
   $('#txtDateOfBirthApplicant').attr('data-datetype', dateType);
});
```

If you want to get the value of date type:

```
let dateType = $('#txtDateOfBirthApplicant').attr('data-datetype');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I mean this calendar the user can change from hijri to gregorian and vise versa , so document ready render the type in the first time but after that it still the same although the user change it.